# Unity buttons sometimes black out in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I recently started developing in Unity and I like it a lot so far, but there is this one bug, I can't tell where it comes from and similar reports of others I read didn't help me.

The problem is that buttons sometimes (almost always by now, not so often in earlier versions of my project) are straight up black and have very dark grey text in them, which is completely different from how they are supposed to look like.

Even if I put all buttons of the color to straight white, this happens - only in Android btw! (Not tested in iOS, but it's neither happening in the editor, nor in desktop builds.

As I said, this **seems to** happen more often, now that the game got bigger, has more buttons etc. - so I would guess that is has something to do with setting the Source Image of those buttons to UISprite. Also this **does not** happen to buttons that have an actual image as Source Image, not the default UISprite.

So this is an example of how it is supposed to look like
[image]

And this is how it actually looks like:[image]

Has someone got an idea? I assume it is something about loading the UISprite.

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem, but I saw this happens sometimes when the image size was too big for the device to show correctly (not enough memory), so Unity freaks out and don't render anything, resulting in this. But as you said that it only happens with buttons using UISprite, I'm not sure..

Comment: Ok, this definately seems to relate to the size of textures I use. For some reason it didn't happen now for 3 times, after i scaled down Android texture sizes to 512. I know there is some hard boundary at like 2048 or 4096 where it won't work for most devices, but my biggest texture is 1920x1080, so this shouldn't happen. Also, why would it have happened **sometimes** ealier then?

Comment: What version of Unity3D are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, the correct answer was what I thought (see my comment).

Too big textures are hardly supported by Android devices, because of the heavy memory consumption. Scaling down all textures should solve the problem. You can also simply add a lower scale of the texture and switch it before rendering if the device is a mobile. Add a script to your buttons and insert this :

```
public Image loweredSprite;
public Button button;

void Start() {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    button.image.overrideSprite(loweredSprite);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Actually no need to do it like that. In the editor you can click on an image and in the inspector click the Android icon and check "override for Android" and set max size right there.